# How to concatenate two matrix column by column?

Tags: r, matrix, concatenation, cbind

Let's say I have two matrices A and B with the same dimensions like follow:

```
A = matrix(1:30, nrow=3, ncol=10)
B = matrix(30:1, nrow=3, ncol=10)
#dim(A) = dim(B)
#[1]  3 10
A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    4    7   10   13   16   19   22   25    28
[2,]    2    5    8   11   14   17   20   23   26    29
[3,]    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27    30
B
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   30   27   24   21   18   15   12    9    6     3
[2,]   29   26   23   20   17   14   11    8    5     2
[3,]   28   25   22   19   16   13   10    7    4     1
```

Is there an R function to concatenate these two matrices column by column to get a single matrix as follows?

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,]    1   30    4   27    7   24   10   21   13    18    16    15    19    12    22     9    25     6    28     3
[2,]    2   29    5   26    8   23   11   20   14    17    17    14    20    11    23     8    26     5    29     2
[3,]    3   28    6   25    9   22   12   19   15    16    18    13    21    10    24     7    27     4    30     1
```

here is my code, is there any way to optimize it?

```
C = matrix(NA, nrow=3, ncol=20)
j=1
for(i in 1:10){
  C[,j] = A[,i]
  C[,j+1] = B[,i]
  j=j+2
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `matrix(rbind(A,B), nrow=3)`

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
matrix(rbind(A,B), nrow=3, ncol=20)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `cbind` the two matrices and then select alternating columns from first half and second half of combined matrix :

```
mat <- cbind(A, B)
inds <- (ncol(mat)/2)
mat[, c(rbind(1:inds, (inds + 1):ncol(mat)))]


#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
#[1,]    1   30    4   27    7   24   10   21   13    18    16
#[2,]    2   29    5   26    8   23   11   20   14    17    17
#[3,]    3   28    6   25    9   22   12   19   15    16    18

#     [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
#[1,]    15    19    12    22     9    25     6    28     3
#[2,]    14    20    11    23     8    26     5    29     2
#[3,]    13    21    10    24     7    27     4    30     1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `asplit` the split the matrices into a `list` and then with `Map`, we can `rbind`

```
t(do.call(rbind, Map(rbind, asplit(A, 2), asplit(B, 2))))
#.    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
#[1,]    1   30    4   27    7   24   10   21   13    18    16    15    19    12    22     9    25     6    28     3
#[2,]    2   29    5   26    8   23   11   20   14    17    17    14    20    11    23     8    26     5    29     2
#[3,]    3   28    6   25    9   22   12   19   15    16    18    13    21    10    24     7    27     4    30     1
```